# Notepad++ open and start monitoring

Tags: windows-10, notepad++

I've looked into --help from notepad++ but there is not mention of this, so I'm asking here, is there a way to open a file and to automatically start monitoring the file?

Normally what I do is I open a file and then I have to go to menu View > Monitoring (tail -f) but I was hoping there might be some hidden way to automatically do this as soon as I open a file, maybe with some hidden magic flag.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the ***Document Monitor*** plugin.

You can install it in from the **Plugins Admin** (Plugins > Plugins Admin) or from the source https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/DocMonitor/

Once installed you click on **Plugins** > **Document Monitor** > **Start to monitor**, and this will be in effect for all files even after closing and reopening Notepad++ (until you go again to *Plugins* > *Document Monitor* and press on ***Stop monitoring***.)

(It refreses every 3 seconds, not realtime.)