# notepad++ different behavior based on file type - auto scroll to the bottom and start monitoring (tail) when opening *.log files

Tags: notepad++, script

Whenever i open log file in Notepad++, I'd like to automatically scroll to the bottom and enable monitoring (tail). I know of Settings - misc.- Update silently and scroll down after update, however I'd like this to be applied to log files only, and scroll to bottom automatically upon opening, regardless of if any update comes in. Don't think this is built-in, can I at least (how?) achieve this via scripting?  ('Opening a log file' for me means double click on a *.log file in any file browser in windows)

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1669721/763386

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! What has this to do with python? Please do only use tags that are relevant to your question.

Comment: you're right, I've removed the python flag (I'm familiar with it and its one of the scripting languages within notepad++ so I wanted to clumsily hint solutions using it, but any solution is more important to me than particular language used)